# Why I cannot use 'order' in sunspot search?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot

I have a column called `cached_votes_up` in Communities table. 
Now I'd like to fetch the records ordered by its number.

```
@search = Community.search do  
    fulltext params[:search]
    with(:genre_id, params[:genre])
            order_by :cached_votes_up, :desc
    paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 5
end 

@communities = @search.results
```

But this returns the following error:

> No field configured for Community with name 'cached_votes_up'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to index the `cached_votes_up` attribute of your object. Add these lines in your `Community` model:

```
searchable do
  integer :cached_votes_up
end
```